# How to format the Footer's entire row and not just the value in row grouping?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm following the AG Grid documentation example here [React Data Grid Row Grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grouping-footers/#example-customising-footer-cells) and quoting the code excerpt I'm interested in below. What should I do there to modify the entire group-level row background color? I consoled out the props but I have no idea where to look ...

**MyInnerRenderer.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  const footer = props.node.footer;
  const isRootLevel = props.node.level === -1;
  const value = props.value;

  if (footer) {
    if (isRootLevel) {
      return (
        <span style={{ color: 'navy', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Grand Total</span>
      );
    } else {
      return <span style={{ color: 'navy' }}>Sub Total {value}</span>;
    }
  } else {
    return <span>{value}</span>;
  }
};
```